# IE fixed header

Tags: css, internet-explorer

Is IE9 going to allow tbody scrolling via css?

Comment: Is that required by a standard?

Comment: Beats me.  I have seen it done in FF.  Is this specific to their browser?  Is FF forking the standard on this?

Comment: If there is a standard, then I suspect they'll try to support it.  If not, then no.  The Preview is a good place to start, or you can try some of the MSDN forums, but the product people don't really monitor them.

Comment: "Table rows may be grouped into a table head, table foot, and one or more table body sections, using the THEAD, TFOOT and TBODY elements, respectively. This division enables user agents to support scrolling of table bodies independently of the table head and foot. When long tables are printed, the table head and foot information may be repeated on each page that contains table data."

http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/tables.html#h-11.2.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go and [find out for yourself](http://ie.microsoft.com/testdrive/).

Comment: Thanks for the link, but I'm not using Windows Vista or Windows 7.  Funny, that site is not exactly ie8 friendly.  I think that Acid3 test is almost painful.

Comment: Yeah well the results are much better in ie9, esp the css selectors. They got a pretty interesting blog too, maybe you can find out there http://blogs.msdn.com/ie/

Comment: Didn't see it there, but I did find someone asking about it for ie8:  

"Do you intend to support the CSS overflow property for TABLE and TBODY elements in IE8? even if it is not strictly standardized would be a nice addition (e.g. FF supports is)"